# Word choice noun vs gerund

Tags: word-choice

This is the quote from a website.

> If you are in need of experienced professionals for adequate **translating** and **interpreting**, and if you care about the quality and the cost of translation, you have come to the right place

Is it correct to use *translating* and *interpreting* in this context? Aren't *translation* and *interpretation* more suitable in this case?

Comment: Both _translation_ and _translating_ sounds correct to me. There is a difference between using _translation_, but I cannot explain it in few words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree the form I would have expected as a native speaker of American English would have been *translation* and *interpretation* . However, an argument can be made that the gerund form conveys more "activity" and "present timeliness" about the proffered service. Especially in the case of "interpreting" I would be wondering if they were offering real-time translation services. Now the question can be asked whether that was their intent, but that's what the difference in phrasing evoked for me.